# Hyperlink relative to current URL not path of user control

Tags: asp.net

I have a page on my site, for purposes of this example lets say http://myhost/Pages/Default.aspx.  On Default.aspx I have a user control called MyControl.ascx which lives in /Controls/MyControl.ascx. So the tree looks something like this

- Root

  - Pages

    - Default.aspx
  - Controls

    - MyControl.ascx

Whenever I place a HyperLink control on MyControl.ascx and specify a NavigateUrl, this path is relative to the control, not the URL of the page. So for instance if in NavigateUrl I specified "AboutMe.aspx", the URL would be rendered as http://myhost/Controls/AboutMe.aspx instead of http://myhost/Pages/AboutMe.aspx. Is there any way I can make this relative to the page URL? I've tried the solution here: [Relative path from an ASP.NET user control NavigateUrl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604636/relative-path-from-an-asp-net-user-control-navigateurl) but it didn't work for me.

**Edit**

To clarify, I'd like this to be generic enough so that if I didn't know what the path was the solution would work.  So I don't really want to harcode "~/Pages/Default.aspx" in the NavigateUrl

Comment: Please share the updated code for the HyperLink control. I'm facing the same problem, and the places where I use the control is not constant.  So cannot hardcode the `~\xyx\xyz\myControl.aspx?` url. I want the relative url from my page.

Comment: @SunnyRGupta I ended up just adding runat="server" to all my <a> tags and then using the "~" operator to get the application root (see #1 from Kelsey's answer below). Although passing the URL in as a property certainly would work. Being that it's been about 2 1/2 years since I posted this I'm a little rusty as to what exactly I was trying to accomplish with this question :)

Comment: thank you for the response, I've already solved the issue on my end.  For others who end up on this page via Google, here is what I did: Used links from root by using "/pathtopage/page.xyz"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a bunch of options:

1. You could hardcode the Url using the `~` operator which give you the root and then define it from there like: `~/Pages/AboutMe.aspx`.  Keep in mind that the `~` operator is recognized only for server controls and in server code.
2. You could also use the `..` to get you to where you want as it will navigate back up the folder structure like: `../Pages/AboutMe.aspx`
3. You could create a helper methods to return you a valid root to your Pages folder, Images, Javascript, etc...
4. The `HttpRequest.ApplicationPath` will get your the virtual application's root path on the server which you can use to build off.

For more information on Pathing options you should read this article on MSDN:

[ASP.NET Web Project Paths](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178116.aspx)

**EDIT:** Based on your edit to your question, you should then pass in the relative  URL into you user control via a property.  Let the page that uses the control define the relative path to the resource it will require.

Comment: @Kyle do you have some other requirements that would make passing in the relative url you want to use not work?

Comment: No, that is probably the best solution for me then. Sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to achieve this is to use

```
 string.Format("{0}", Page.Request.Url.PathAndQuery);
```

in NavigateUrl property

Comment: This gives you the non-url rewrite version, plus the posted data.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone else stumbles across this as I did...

In the code behind, I set the NavigateUrl to:

```
link.NavigateUrl = Page.ResolveUrl("aboutus.aspx");
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you set the NavigateUrl of the hyperlink? If I set it using the `~` character, then it works as expected:

MyControl.ascx

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/Pages/Default.aspx" ... >
```

Answer (score 0):

Simpler than that. Just change the usercontrol's AppRelativeTemplateSourceDirectory property to the value of the same property of the parent Page.

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    AppRelativeTemplateSourceDirectory = Page.AppRelativeTemplateSourceDirectory;
    base.OnInit(e);
}
```

then all relative path in user control will be if there was in page.