# ReturnURL messed up when a page links to itself

Tags: html, asp.net, url, redirect, returnurl

I have a `home.aspx` and `about.aspx` in the root directory, an Account folder which included `login.aspx`, `register.aspx`, `manage.aspx`.

I have a navbar which includes links to all the relevant pages depending on whether the user is logged in or not.
Suppose if he is at the `login.aspx` page and he clicks again on the link to `/login.aspx`, the return URL becomes `ReturnUrl="localhost:xxxx/Account/Account/login.aspx"`
If I click on `register.aspx` now, it becomes `Account/Account/Account/register.aspx`

What is this called and how to rectify it?
I think I need to make something like a virtual root directory relative to which all addresses are resolved.
My hrefs are like this,

```
<li id="RegisterLink" runat="server"><a href="Account/Register.aspx"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Register</a></li>
<li id="LoginLink" runat="server"><a href="Account/Login.aspx"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
```

Comment: Look at this answer, it will help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/3567721/713789

Comment: Thanks for that. I've added that as an answer with a link to the original source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sharing the below solution from another thread which seems to work in my situation too (Source https://stackoverflow.com/a/3567721/4594699)

> You have a bunch of options:
>
> 1. You could hardcode the Url using the `~` operator which give you the root and then define it from there like: `~/Pages/AboutMe.aspx`.  Keep in mind that the `~` operator is recognized only for server controls and in server code.
> 2. You could also use the `..` to get you to where you want as it will navigate back up the folder structure like: `../Pages/AboutMe.aspx`
> 3. You could create a helper methods to return you a valid root to your Pages folder, Images, Javascript, etc...
> 4. The `HttpRequest.ApplicationPath` will get your the virtual application's root path on the server which you can use to build off.
>
> For more information on Pathing options you should read this article on MSDN:
>
> [ASP.NET Web Project Paths](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178116.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You use relative anchor instead of an absolute one.
Try To change :

```
<a href="Account/Register.aspx">
```

To :

```
<a href="/Account/Register.aspx">
```

You can try this one too :

```
<a href="../config2.aspx">
```

Maybe if you remove the account will fix it :

```
<a href="Register.aspx">
```

Or just try with this :

```
<a href="~/Account/Register.aspx">
```

Or organize your folders in other way.

Comment: The last one did it for me. Also Anirugu's comment on my question works for a lot of scenarios.